# Cannot deploy - nothing happens when I click "Deploy"

Tags: battlefield-4

I'm able to join games in BF4 and all that, I was just playing yesterday but today I can't spawn or deploy - what is causing this and how do I fix it?

When I am viewing the map and I click deploy - nothing happens, no load, no blank screen, no freeze, nothing - absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't spawn or deploy"? Are you clicking on the button and nothing's happening? Does the screen go black when trying to go to the deploy screen? Does the game freeze?

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Are you in a squad when this happens? Can you change spawn points between objectives and squad members?

Comment: I just join in a game solo, I've tried in conquest and team deathmatch - but no matter where i click or what camp I click on to deploy - it just does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently it's part of a punkbuster problem.

Just run pbsetup and update your punkbuster to the new version.

For the people who don't know how to install or update.

1. Download pbsetup from the [official website](http://www.punkbuster.com/index.php?page=pbsetup.php).
2. Run it's Installation and it will open a window.
3. If your game is not there, click "ADD GAME" and choose your game and click UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

I've also experience the problem. In addition to what is described above, I've also experienced matches where my minimap icon would appear and I have the option to redeploy.

Some users have reported success with this fix: http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/forum/threadview/2955064772515425961/

Comment: I feel like this punkbuster website is like a phishing website... it looks so fake. Is this punkbuster website listed in the link a legit resource? It doesn't even own the trademarks.

Comment: Should have taken a more in depth look prior to posting, it looks dodgy/10

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, yes, it's the proper site.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an unexpected side-effect of the R20 patch. I found I had the same issue yesterday when I played Golmud Railway on Obliteration mode. Other players had issues on Locker and Siege of Shanghai. For me, I managed to deploy after waiting a few minutes. There's been mentions of a R21 patch being released today on the Battlefield 4 subreddit page.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has now been fixed as part of the late Janurary patch.